# Function my_find_node that returns the address of the first node occurence

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I need help to write a function according to these instructions:

> Write a function named my_find_node that returns the address of the
>   first node occurence, which contains data equal to the reference data.
>   If no such node is found, NULL should be returned.
>
> It must be prototyped as follows:
>
> linked_list_t *my_find_node(linked_list_t *list, const int data_ref);

For the moment, my code doesn't compile for some reason.

I have made a header file named my_list.h which contains:

```
    #ifndef __MYLIST__H__
    #define __MYLIST__H__

    typedef struct linked_list_t
    {
    int x;
    struct linked_list_t *next;
    }linked_list_t;

linked_list_t *my_find_node(linked_list_t *list, const int data_ref);

#endif
```

And here is the declaration of my function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"


linked_list_t *my_find_node(linked_list_t *list, const int data_ref)
    {
        linked_list_t *current = list;

        int count = 0;

        if(current == NULL)
            return (NULL);

    while (list != NULL)
    {
        if (count == data_ref)
            return element;

        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

If someone can help me to make it work or give me any clue, would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was trying to match the Nth element in the list and *not* a match to the content/value of the node.

Also, `element` wasn't defined. And, you were doing `while (list != NULL)` but doing `current = current->next`, so, in effect, you had `while (1)` amongst other problems.

It's actually a bit simpler, based on the problem definition (i.e. ***contains** data equal to the reference data*). Here's a slightly refactored version:

```
linked_list_t *
my_find_node(linked_list_t *list,const int data_ref)
{
    linked_list_t *current;

    for (current = list;  current != NULL;  current = current->next) {
        if (current->x == data_ref)
            break;
    }

    return current;
}
```